# Installing python module in windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, module

I am trying to install a Python module in Windows 7 (`beautifulsoup`). It is the first module I am trying to install, but I am receiving a strange message after the command `setup.py` to install:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Python33\python.exe'
```

Any idea what is happening? I'm using a user with local admin rights; could it be some problem related to the security policies in my Windows 7?
Any other alternative to install packages?

Comment: Could you give us more info (python version you're using etc.) ?

Comment: couuld you edit and add the full command line output and input?

Comment: I am using python3.3. These are the two ways I am trying, exceuted from the folder where the setup.py is: C:\Python33\dowloaded\beautifulsoup4-4.1.3>setup.py install
Unable to create process using 'C:\Python33\python.exe "C:\Python33\dowloaded\be
autifulsoup4-4.1.3\setup.py"  install'

C:\Python33\dowloaded\beautifulsoup4-4.1.3>c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py insta
ll
This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your syst
em administrator.

Comment: Did you try to run cmd.exe as administrator ?

Answer (score 0):

You must set your environmental variables:

- right click on computer
- properties
- advanced settings
- system properties
- environmental variables
- add new
- value name = python, variable value = C:\users\local\bin\python33 /
- click ok and you will see what was added to drop down window below.

Remember that when you downloaded Python it went to its own directory. You need to find where the python3.3exe is located and make sure every thing is in place. In your program view open python idle
editor and at the >>> print ("Hello World") and see if all is ok.

From BigMAC